# Has DynamicReports been deleted from the Internet?

Tags: dynamic-reports

While researching reporting tools for Java I saw a lot of good feedback on [DynamicReports](http://www.dynamicreports.org).  The web site doesn't exist any longer, however.  Does anyone know what happened to DynamicReports?

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/dynamicreports/dynamicreports. So the original author cannot be contacted, however there is soon to be a concerted effort, in continuing with what is seen to have been valuable tool one which many had come to appreciate. This project is now seeking contributions from willing participants, to maintain the work of Ricardo Mariarca

Answer (score 2):

The site www.dynamicreports.org is maintained by the company jaspersoft, on page
News from DynamicReports does not know anything about this site's ofiline status

https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/dynamicreports

I asked a question asking for more information about the site we are
https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1100606/dynamicreportsorg-offline

add a question there too

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
I found this link with examples.


https://dynamicreports.lbayer.com/